# serverless offline exec does return exit code

Tags: gitlab-ci, serverless, serverless-offline

I am running the following code in a ci/cd pipeline:

```
sls offline start --showDuration --exec "npm run int-test"
```

However, when a test fails, the ci/cd pipeline does not fail because the failure of a test is not trickling down to the script, which is serverless offline exec is not passing the exit code.

I could get past this if I had a way of shutting down serverless offline in the pipeline.  I could start the server, run tests, shut down the server.  However, I cannot find a stop command for serverless offline, and Ctrl-C is no an option cause I am running in the pipeline, not on a terminal.

Suggestions on getting either of these solutions to work?  Right now my pipeline thinks my tests are passing...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `start` option of that command. For what I understand from this [Github issue](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/727#issuecomment-508002836) it might be the solution for that particular problem. It helped me with something similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work for me on versions `Framework Core: 2.6.0 (local)
Plugin: 4.0.4
SDK: 2.3.2
Components: 3.2.1`